# How can i use radiobuttonlist to show the table from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, radiobuttonlist, sqlyog

On selection of the radiobutton list I would like to query the database for the total and balances. In my database named **eleave** , I have 3 tables **Annual** , **Special** , **Maternity**.

Inside the table, I have **total** and **balance** columns for each type of leave.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblleavetype" runat="server" CellPadding="0" 
                        CellSpacing="0" style="text-align: left" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="rblleavetype_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="al">Annualleave</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="ml">Maternity leave</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="sp">Special</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

This is the table codes for display the output.

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" 
                            style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 400px">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #D39A05; height: 25px; width: 200px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                                    Total days for this leave type</td>
                                <td 
                                    style="border-left: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center;
                                    background-color: #D39A05; height: 25px; width: 200px; vertical-align: top;">
                                    Balance days available for this leave type</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center; width: 200px; vertical-align: top;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="ltotalleavetype" runat="server" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                                    days</td>
                                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 200px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbalanceleavetype" runat="server" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                                    days</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

I have been working on this system for months now and I still cant find the solution. p.s. I am still new in C# world.

Comment: You would handle your event in the rblleavetype_SelectedIndexChanged method. There you would take the value passed by your radiobutton list rblleavetype.SelectedValue then write a query to access your database to pull the data for the value selected. You can render the data better binding it to a gridview or a datareader. You say you have been working on this for months so I'm wondering what I'm missing because this seems like a process that should be straight forward with a few google searches. Please explain the issue in more depth.

Comment: Totally agree with @vikingben

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer? Did it help you?

Comment: hi @Sam , i've tried implements your given codes, but it resulted in "Namespace 'name' not found".

Comment: If you use the code that I shared as is it should work because I tried it. But, if you update the question with what you've tried maybe I could help.

Comment: If you create a new web application and follow my instructions you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are new to web development using ASP.Net (or maybe you are being lazy. Just kidding :-D). Anyway, hope this will help you and someone in future.

First of all you need to have `AutoPostBack="true"` in your `RadioButtonList`. Then only it'll send a postback to the server and call the `rblleavetype_SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Ok, I created a working sample (Code is self explanatory and I've added comments where necessary). I'll explain the steps to display your data in a html table based on the radio button selection.

**STEPS**

1. Create a web page (I'm calling it `LeaveBalance.aspx`) with a RabioButtonList and the table (as you've already done).

```
<form id="frmLeaves" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblleavetype" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" style="text-align: left" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="rblleavetype_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="al">Annual leave</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="ml">Maternity leave</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="sp">Special</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 400px">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #D39A05; height: 25px; width: 200px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                Total days for this leave type</td>
            <td 
                style="border-left: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center;
                background-color: #D39A05; height: 25px; width: 200px; vertical-align: top;">
                Balance days available for this leave type</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center; width: 200px; vertical-align: top;">
                <asp:Label ID="ltotalleavetype" runat="server" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                days</td>
            <td style="border-left: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; width: 200px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lbalanceleavetype" runat="server" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                days</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

2. Then in your code behind file (LeaveBalance.aspx.cs) you should define your `rblleavetype_SelectedIndexChanged` method and some logic to load initial values at `Page_Load` event.

using System;

using MyLeave;

```
public partial class LeaveBalance : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     // This is your UI logic.
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a private variable to hold all your leave retrieved from the database
    /// I assume you have you'll have one row for each leave type
    /// </summary>
    public LeaveCollection AllLeaves {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["AllLeaves"] != null)
            {
                return (LeaveCollection)ViewState["AllLeaves"];
            }
            return new LeaveCollection();
        }
        set
        {
            // You need to save the collection in ViewState to persist the data
            // Otherwise you'll loose all values AllLeaves will be reset in every postback
            ViewState["AllLeaves"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetAllLeavesFromDatabase();
        }

        // I assume that annual leave radio option will be selected initially when the page loads
        LoadDisplayTable(LeaveType.AL);
    }

    protected void rblleavetype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LeaveType type = LeaveType.AL;

        switch (rblleavetype.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "ml":
                type = LeaveType.ML;
                break;
            case "sp":
                type = LeaveType.SP;
                break;
        }

        LoadDisplayTable(type);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all leaves from database.
    /// </summary>
    private void GetAllLeavesFromDatabase()
    {
        AllLeaves = new LeaveCollection();
        /* At this point you should know how to retrieve your leave data from DB and fill the AllLeaves collection
         E.g.

         AllLeaves = DalService.GetAllLeavesFromDatabase(); // DalService could be your Data Access layer and GetAllLeavesFromDatabase() is one of it's methods

         I'll be creating some dummy logic to fill the collection for demo purpose from this point onwards

         */

        // Add annual leave to the collection
        Leave al = new Leave(LeaveType.AL);
        al.TotalDays = 15;
        al.Available = 10;
        AllLeaves.Add(al);

        // Add Maternity leave
        Leave ml = new Leave(LeaveType.ML);
        ml.TotalDays = 60;
        ml.Available = 5;
        AllLeaves.Add(ml);

        // Add Special leave
        Leave sl = new Leave(LeaveType.SP);
        sl.TotalDays = 5;
        sl.Available = 3;
        AllLeaves.Add(sl);
    }

    private void LoadDisplayTable(LeaveType type)
    {
        Leave selectedLeave = new Leave(type);

        if (AllLeaves != null && AllLeaves.Count > 0)
        {
            // Here we find the leave object in the collection based on the leave type
            selectedLeave = AllLeaves.Find(a => a.LeaveType == type);
        }

        // Populate your labels with selected leave type
        ltotalleavetype.Text = selectedLeave.TotalDays.ToString();
        lbalanceleavetype.Text = selectedLeave.Available.ToString();
    }
}
```

3. The Leave class is created to hold the leave data (`Leave.cs`)

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

```
namespace MyLeave
{
    // This is your modal. It defines how you'd hold your leave data in memory
    // This collection will hold all your leaves
    [Serializable]
    public class LeaveCollection : List<Leave> { }

    // Base class to create your leave
    [Serializable] // Since you are saving the object in ViewState you need to mark this class as Serializable

    public class Leave
    {
        public LeaveType LeaveType { get; set; }
        public int TotalDays { get; set; }
        public int Available { get; set; }

        public Leave(LeaveType type)
        {
            this.LeaveType = type;
            this.TotalDays = 0;
            this.Available = 0;
        }
    }

    // This Enum will hold the leave type
    public enum LeaveType
    {
        AL = 1,
        ML = 2,
        SP = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Vote and accept the answer if it answered your question